`_.template` lodash feature is not compiling when moving from offline to online in mobile app development
I am using _.template from lodash to create a compiled template for Emails subject in my app development. Its working good in online..When I do something in offline app(which is offline enable app) and then move to online _.template is not compiling leads to sending invalid emails. Attached screenshot for the same
Lodash Version : 4.17.11
var compiled_email = _.template('<p style="line-height: 1.5;">Test content</p><p>Action plan identifier: ${ identifier }</p><p>Action category: ${ actioncategory }</p><p>Type of action plan: ${ actiontype }</p><p>Activity: ${ activity }</p><p>Due date: ${ duedate }</p><p><br></p>');
var result = compiled_email({
    'identifier': 'testa',
    'actioncategory': 'testb',
    'actiontype': 'testc',
    'activity': 'testd',
    'duedate': 'teste'

});

Result
enter image description here
